# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ':' delimiter: line 1 column 57358 (char 57357)

Tags: python, json

I am getting a JSON response from the server and storing it in a text file
Later I parse certain data from the text file, but while doing so I am getting the above error. The JSON format seems to be okay to me Can you please help me here. Thanks Also I do not have any control over the response I receive from the server. For now, I am just using dump to write it to a text file

Code for json `dump` and `load`

```
balance = exchange.fetch_balance()
        #print(balance)
    with open('balance.txt', 'w') as json_file:
        json.dump(balance, json_file)
        print("Balance file created")

        with open('balance.txt') as json_file:
            data = json.load(json_file)
            freeusdt = float(data['info']['balances'][11]['free'])
            Qty=float(df['close'][last_row_index])
            Qty=Qty+300
            buyqty=freeusdt/Qty
```

My JSON file is here (in the .txt file Since StackOverflow won't let me post the full code as it exceeds the character limit)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kpBMl6JbzlH9OQvvteLl0Ieb2PaBU_kr/view?usp=sharing

The full error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pavan.alur\Desktop\SUPERTRENDWITHKAMA\supertrendwithkama.py", line 232, in <module>
    schedule.run_pending()
  File "C:\Users\pavan.alur\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\schedule\__init__.py", line 780, in run_pending
    default_scheduler.run_pending()
  File "C:\Users\pavan.alur\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\schedule\__init__.py", line 100, in run_pending
    self._run_job(job)
  File "C:\Users\pavan.alur\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\schedule\__init__.py", line 172, in _run_job
    ret = job.run()
  File "C:\Users\pavan.alur\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\schedule\__init__.py", line 661, in run
    ret = self.job_func()
  File "C:\Users\pavan.alur\Desktop\SUPERTRENDWITHKAMA\supertrendwithkama.py", line 223, in run_bot
    check_buy_sell_signals(supertrend_data)
  File "C:\Users\pavan.alur\Desktop\SUPERTRENDWITHKAMA\supertrendwithkama.py", line 121, in check_buy_sell_signals
    data1 = json.load(json_file1)
  File "C:\Users\pavan.alur\Miniconda3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "C:\Users\pavan.alur\Miniconda3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\pavan.alur\Miniconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\pavan.alur\Miniconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ':' delimiter: line 1 column 57358 (char 57357)
```

Comment: Close the file before you open it again!

Comment: @KlausD. Thanks for the comment, isn't the whole point of using `with` is that it is not necessary to close the file

Comment: Your second `with` block is contained within the first. Indentation counts in Python.

Comment: No, the point is to get the file automatically closed when *leaving* the block.

Comment: @MattDMo yes that solved it. Silly me. I am new to python straight from C#.
will keep in mind regarding indentation. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: @KlausD. I know right I never left the first with (the one that loads) before reading it again Thanks for the help. Have a great day!!!

Answer (score 0):

The indentation problem as mentioned by @MattDMo solved it

```
balance = exchange.fetch_balance()

with open('balance.txt', 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(balance, json_file)
    print("Balance file created")

with open('balance.txt') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    freeusdt = float(data['info']['balances'][11]['free'])
    Qty=float(df['close'][last_row_index])
    Qty=Qty+300
    buyqty=freeusdt/Qty
```

Comment: I fixed your code slightly - everything should be at the same indentation level. I strongly suggest reading [PEP 8 -- The Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: Thanks!@MattDMo